# I'm using tkinter GUI and winsound but stop function is not working

Tags: python, tkinter-layout

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound  
from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC
root = Tk()
root.configure(background='light green')

def playing():
    winsound.PlaySound('alarm', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

def stop_sound():
    PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)
```

Button(root,text="playing ",font=("Helvetica 15"),command=playing).pack(pady=20)
Button(root,text="Stop",font=("Helvetica 15"),command=stop_sound).pack(pady=20)

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix Updated**

In your `playing` function
You can replace `winsoud.PlaySound` and `winsound.SND_FILENAME` with `PlaySound` and `SND_FILENAME`.

The complete code will look like this

```py
from tkinter import *
from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC
root = Tk()
root.configure(background='light green')

def playing(): PlaySound('alarm', SND_FILENAME)

def stop_sound(): PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)

Button(root,text="playing ",font=("Helvetica 15"),command=playing).pack(pady=20)
Button(root,text="Stop",font=("Helvetica 15"),command=stop_sound).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

**Description**

The idea is same. The program doesn't know what winsound is since we are not importing it. But the functions we are calling are imported. So no need to prefix them with `winsound.`

**Fix**

Include this line with other imports

```
import winsound
```

**Description**

From looking at the code you are not importing the 'winsound' module. You are including from it by not the module itself.

**Note**

When asking question on StackOverflow kindly share your exceptions/log messages so people can help you easily

Comment: from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Radha\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-2-9ec852ebff37>", line 7, in playing
    winsound.PlaySound('alarm', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
NameError: name 'winsound' is not defined

Comment: I import winsound so now playing ()function is working but stop_sound() function  is not working